# Algorithm for time-domain pattern matching

Tags: time-series, pattern-recognition

I have the following problem: I have a hypothesized pattern of a sensor that will most likely fall into four categories A, B, C, or D. Each sample reading contains the same amount of datapoints. My real sensor data would be really easy to match to the hypothesized pattern "by inspection", but there might be some differences that make it hard to be done automatically, i.e. a time-shift or an offset. I have one sample attached where the data is rather similar, but it is also possible that the sensor reading might be shifted by a few seconds.

[image: Sample Hypothesis]
[image: Sample Actual Sensor Reading]

I am looking for some algorithm that is able to match the recorded sensor data to one of my four patterns.

Comment: I think you may look at the paper `Shape Expressions for Specifying and Extracting Signal Features` by Dejan Nickovic et al. Authors exactly solve the problem you describe. Link: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-030-32079-9_17